# How to extract a number between two tags in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

print soup.prettify()
```

```
        <td>
         Chinese Yuan Renminbi
        </td>
        <td class="rtRates">
         <a href="/graph/?from=USD&amp;to=CNY">
          6.887711
         </a>
        </td>
        <td class="rtRates">
         <a href="/graph/?from=CNY&amp;to=USD">
          0.145186
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
```

May I ask that how can I extract the content between tag 'a'?
Say I want to get 6.887711 in the 6th row of the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.find_all()` to iterate through all of them:

```
for tag in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Which would output:

```
6.887711
0.145186
...
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to extract 6.887711 only what should I do?

Comment: Where do you see `6.887711` being the 6th row? When I go to the site it's the 10th row.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the first tag, you can make use of the `href` difference and use *regex* to match the corresponding tag; For instance the `href` for the first tag ends with `CNY`, using `re` module with regex `CNY$` to match the `href` attribute:

```
import re
soup.find("a", {"href": re.compile("CNY$")}).text
# '6.888069'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a situation like this you might consider using the lxml library because it makes `xpath` available.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'http://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=USD&amount=1'
>>> HTML = requests.get(url).text
>>> parser = etree.HTMLParser()
>>> tree = etree.fromstring(HTML, parser=parser)
>>> currency = tree.xpath('.//table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]')
>>> currency[0].text
'Bahraini Dinar'
>>> USDrate = tree.xpath('.//table[2]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a')
>>> USDrate[0].text
'2.652179'
```

In this case I have found the second table, then the third row of that table and then the first and third cells of that row.